# how to stop current fragment media player when moved to next fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I have two Fragments with tabLayout and I am trying to stop current sound of a fragment when i want to play sound in another fragment
this is my adapter class

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.holder> {

public Context context;
String data[];
int images[];
int sound[];

holder h;
int playPosition = -1;

public Adapter() {
}

//constructor
public Adapter(String[] data, int[] images, int[] sound, Context context) {

    this.data = data;
    this.images = images;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.context = context;

    h = null;
    playPosition = -1;
}

//class holder
public class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    AppCompatImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;


    public holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleview, parent, false);
    return new holder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final holder holder, final int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(data[position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                if (holder.mPlayer != null) {
                    holder.mPlayer.release();
                    holder.mPlayer = null;
                }
                holder.mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound[position]);
                // stops the previous sound
                if (h != null && playPosition != -1 && position != playPosition) {
                    h.mPlayer.stop();
                    h.mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound[playPosition]);

                }
                holder.mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                        holder.mPlayer.start();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                                holder.mPlayer = null;
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // holder.playIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            h = holder;
            playPosition = position;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length;
}
```

}

and this is my fragment

```
public class NatureForest extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;

public NatureForest() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    String tab2Text[] = {"Forest forest","Forest creek","Forest leaves","Forest birds",
            "Forest waterfall","Forest wind","Forest fire",
            "Forest grasshopper", "Forest frogs"};
    int tab2Images[] = {R.drawable.ic_rain2,R.drawable.ic_rain2,R.drawable.ic_rain2,R.drawable.ic_rain2,
            R.drawable.ic_rain2,R.drawable.ic_rain2,R.drawable.ic_rain2,R.drawable.ic_rain2,R.drawable.ic_rain2};
    int sound[]={R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,
            R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,R.raw.sounds,
            R.raw.sounds};
    recyclerView =view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(tab2Text,tab2Images,sound,getContext()));
    return view;
}
```

}

here if a sound in one fragment is played and at the same time another sound played from 2nd fragment , the previous fragment sound is not stopped.

Answer (score 0):

> onPause()

: The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving the fragment. This is usually where you should commit any changes that should be persisted beyond the current user session

Just override this method and pause the mediaplayer instance in that fragment

Comment: how can i access mediaplayer class from holder class of Adapter in my fragment ?

Comment: @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
        adapter.stop();
    }

Comment: you want to pause the media player thats playing in a fragment right . so as soon as you go to other tab the onPause method of the fragment will be called (the fragment you are leaving from) , and you have the mediaplayer instance that you used to play just use tat and pause it

Comment: yes , i understood but how i have my mediaPlayer instance in adapter class so how can i stop it in my fragment ?

Comment: well you can pass it as parameter via constructor that you are calling the adapter from ',  but i am not getting to as why you need media player in adapter

Comment: I am using media Player in adapter class because i have used recycler view and set my views through Adapter and there is need of on click to that view and on click of each view will play sound through media Player

Comment: wouldnt it be better to use interface for that?